# How to split one class' code into a few files?

Tags: c#, file

I'm working with visual studio 2010.

I'd like to split one class into a few .cs files. Is it possible?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
             InitializeComponent();
        }

        int i = 5;
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to add method `public void laugh()` into `public partial class Form1`, but in a different file. How to do that? I don't want that method in a Form1.cs

Comment: What's stopping you? Did you try it? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Any reason why you want this? This makes it hard to read for the one using your code. (Auto generated .cs from VS are an exception )

Comment: I've been doing things like public partial class Form1 : Form
and some of em worked, but then another one design got created and i don't know how to get rid of it

Comment: Many ppl have answered your question - but I just want to point out that the key to separate your code to different files is in the `partial` keyword.

Comment: You do this by declaring the class as `partial`, just as you see there in the designer generated code.  It's a bad practice to create partial classes outside of generated code.  The code is hard to read, track down, piece together.  Dont do it.

Answer (score 4):

Add a new class to your project with an appropriate name (you cannot use `Form1.cs` because it already exists), for example `Form1.Code.cs`. Then this works:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public void laugh()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Haha");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You *can* add a 'Form1.Something.cs' file to your project, to keep it close to 'Form1.cs'.

Use the same namespace and classname and add any code you like:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 // no need to inherit
    {
        public void Laugh() { ... }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In `Form1.part2.cs` (or whatever name you want to give the file):

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 
    {
        public void laugh()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Ensure that the namespace and class name are the same (as well as the accessibility and `partial` modifier) and just add your code. Also ensure the new file is part of the project.

Answer (score 2):

[Partial type definitions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wbx7zzdd%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) MSDN Reference.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the designer generated code. It uses the same method.
Also have a look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Try use this
first file

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
    public void laugh()
 }
}
```

second file

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

     public classForm1()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
     }

     int i = 5;
     private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {

     }
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like the second file is part of the partial class Form1. Wrap it in a `partial class Form1`.

Answer (score 1):

The `partial` keyword does exactly that.

[partial (Type) (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wbx7zzdd%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

The other file would look something like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public void laugh()
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a *new* `CS` file to your project and write inside something like:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
       public void laugh()
       {
       }
    }
}
```

Maintain the *namespace* name and class name with *partial*.

Answer (score 1):

You already have this: Form1.cs and Form1.designer.cs (designer generated stuff)
If you have another file Form1.test.cs and include this in your project, and then wrap it in a partial class:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    partial class Form1 
    {
        public void laugh() 
        {
            //your stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're halfway there already :)  Just add another file alongside the existing Form1.cs to your project - maybe FormMethods.cs?:

```
public partial class Form1 
{
  public void laugh() 
  {
    ...
  }
}
```